# Why net/if.h before ifaddrs.h?

Tags: c, header-files, darwin

Apple's [man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/getifaddrs.3.html) for `getifaddrs` says, under "BUGS",

> If both <net/if.h> and <ifaddrs.h> are being included, <net/if.h> must be included before <ifaddrs.h>.

Why is this?  This looks to be an Apple thing as there's no such caveat in the Linux [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html).

Apple's ifaddrs.h (at least, on my machine) contains this section:

```c
/*
 * This may have been defined in <net/if.h>.  Note that if <net/if.h> is
 * to be included it must be included before this header file.
 */
#ifndef ifa_broadaddr
#define ifa_broadaddr   ifa_dstaddr /* broadcast address interface */
#endif
```

However, my net/if.h doesn't define `ifa_broadaddr` so it's not clear what the conflict would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`<net/if.h>`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-7195.81.3/bsd/net/if.h.auto.html) includes `<net/if_var.h>`:

```c
#include <net/if_var.h>
```

And [`<net/if_var.h>`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-7195.81.3/bsd/net/if_var.h.auto.html) defines it:

```c
#define ifa_broadaddr   ifa_dstaddr     /* broadcast address interface */
```

Note that this definition is always (re)defined in `<net/if_var.h>`.

The definition in `<ifaddrs.h>` is surrounded by `#ifndef` and `#endif` tags to prevent redefinition, which means it can use an alternative definition if it was already defined.

[From the very same documentation you linked](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/getifaddrs.3.html):

> Note that as a convenience, `ifa_broadaddr` is defined by a compiler
> #define directive to be the same as `ifa_dstaddr`.

By including `<net/if.h>` (and thus also `<net/if_var.h>`) before `<ifaddrs.h>`, you ensure the definition of `ifa_broadaddr` matches.